# React-Native Error: Unable to resolve module

Tags: android, react-native

React Native 0.63.4

Out of what seems like nowhere, I'm getting `Error: Unable to resolve module '../../realm' from '/src/my/source/file'`. This isn't really realm specific. It was working until this morning and then I did a fresh install on the android emulator and it is now red screening.

If I change `import Realm from 'realm'` to `import Realm from '../../../node_modules/realm'` it works fine. I've deleted my `node_modules` dir and ran `npm i` again. Cleared any cache I know about. Just have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall just the `Realm` lib? (`npm remove`, `npm i`)

Comment: Ya, good suggestion. But I did try that. I even tried downgrading to a previous minor version just to kind of force something to change.

Comment: This sometimes happens, out of the blue. Sometimes a computer restart solves all of the problems. Aaaah, React Native :) I don't have any suggestions tbh, hope you'll find it!